# How to create a sine curve of positive part only between two integer values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have to generate a sine curve of the positive part only between two values. The idea is my variable say monthly-averaged RH, which has 12 data points in a year (i.e. time series) varies between 50 and 70 in a sinusoidal way. The first and the last data points end at 50.

Can anyone help how I can generate this curve/function for the curve to get values of all intermediate data points? I am trying to use numpy/scipy for this.

Best,

Debayan

Comment: You mean like ```np.sin(np.linspace(0., np.pi, 12)) * 20. + 50.```? 12 equidistant values from 0 to pi (because that is the positive part of a sine wave), scaled and offset appropriately

Answer (score 0):

This is basic trig.

```
import math
for i in range(12):
    print( i, 50 + 20 * math.sin( math.pi * i / 12 ) )
```

Output:

```
0 50.0
1 55.17638090205041
2 60.0
3 64.14213562373095
4 67.32050807568876
5 69.31851652578136
6 70.0
7 69.31851652578136
8 67.32050807568878
9 64.14213562373095
10 60.0
11 55.17638090205042
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but the 12th value should be 50 again. Dividing it by 11 fixes that.

Comment: I suppose that depends on what you want.  If this is an annual cycle, then you'd want every January to be 50 again, not January and December.